# PHP list of specific files in a directory

Tags: php, file, list, directory

The following code will list all the file in a directory

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if (($file != ".") 
         && ($file != ".."))
        {
            $thelist .= '<LI><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>';
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>

<P>List of files:</p>
<UL>
<P><?=$thelist?></p>
</UL>
```

While this is very simple code it does the job.

I'm now looking for a way to list ONLY files that have .xml (or .XML) at the end, how do I do that?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && strtolower(substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1)) == 'xml')
        {
            $thelist .= '<li><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

A simple way to look at the extension using substr and strrpos

Comment: Checking if `$file` is `.` or `..` is useless if you already try to find a certain extension, because that will already exclude those two cases. Also, for security reasons you might want to remove any `..` in the path so that one can only access a sub directory, and not a sibling or parent directory. Consider this only if your directory ain't static.

Comment: This answers the original question, but I think the question should really be "is there an explicit PHP syntax which can do this for you?".  The answer is yes, as you see by the highest up-voted answer.

Answer (score 225):

You'll be wanting to use [`glob()`](http://www.php.net/glob)

Example:

```
$files = glob('/path/to/dir/*.xml');
```

Comment: i'm not a PHP programmer, I'm an old C programmer. Where if the code am I adding that?

Comment: @Jessica you completely replace your code with that single line. It will return an array of all files paths having an xml extension. You can iterate over that with `foreach` to build your HTML list then.

Comment: +1 Awesome answer. I didn’t know about `glob()` and will definitely be using this a lot from now on. Thanks!

Comment: @Jessica This answer seems to be better than the one chosen. How about changing it?

Answer (score 14):

```
$it = new RegexIterator(new DirectoryIterator("."), "/\\.xml\$/i"));

foreach ($it as $filename) {
    //...
}
```

You can also use the recursive variants of the iterators to traverse an entire directory hierarchy.

Comment: In PHP >= 5.3 you could also use the GlobIterator: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.globiterator.php

Comment: Link from @Gordon not working for me, but here's the same content with examples: [GlobIterator::__construct](http://php.net/manual/en/globiterator.construct.php).

Answer (score 5):

I use this code:

```
<?php

{
//foreach (glob("images/*.jpg") as $large) 
foreach (glob("*.xml") as $filename) { 

//echo "$filename\n";
//echo str_replace("","","$filename\n");

echo str_replace("","","<a href='$filename'>$filename</a>\n");

}
}


?>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can mix between glob() function & pathinfo() function  like below.

the below code will show files information for specific extension "pdf"

```
foreach ( glob("*.pdf") as $file ) {

    $file_info = pathinfo( getcwd().'/'.$file );

    echo $file_info['dirname'], "<br>";
    echo $file_info['basename'], "<br>";
    echo $file_info['extension'], "<br>";
    echo $file_info['filename'], "<br>"; 
    echo '<hr>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**LIST FILES and FOLDERS in a directory** (Full Code):
*p.s. you have to **uncomment the 5th line** if you want only for specific extensions*

```
<?PHP
# The current directory
$directory = dir("./");

# If you want to turn on Extension Filter, then uncomment this:
### $allowed_ext = array(".sample", ".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".txt", ".doc", ".xls"); 




## Description of the soft: list_dir_files.php  
## Major credits: phpDIRList 2.0 -(c)2005 Ulrich S. Kapp :: Systemberatung ::

$do_link = TRUE; 
$sort_what = 0; //0- by name; 1 - by size; 2 - by date
$sort_how = 0; //0 - ASCENDING; 1 - DESCENDING


# # #
function dir_list($dir){ 
    $i=0; 
    $dl = array(); 
    if ($hd = opendir($dir))    { 
        while ($sz = readdir($hd)) {  
            if (preg_match("/^\./",$sz)==0) $dl[] = $sz;$i.=1;  
        } 
    closedir($hd); 
    } 
    asort($dl); 
    return $dl; 
} 
if ($sort_how == 0) { 
    function compare0($x, $y) {  
        if ( $x[0] == $y[0] ) return 0;  
        else if ( $x[0] < $y[0] ) return -1;  
        else return 1;  
    }  
    function compare1($x, $y) {  
        if ( $x[1] == $y[1] ) return 0;  
        else if ( $x[1] < $y[1] ) return -1;  
        else return 1;  
    }  
    function compare2($x, $y) {  
        if ( $x[2] == $y[2] ) return 0;  
        else if ( $x[2] < $y[2] ) return -1;  
        else return 1;  
    }  
}else{ 
    function compare0($x, $y) {  
        if ( $x[0] == $y[0] ) return 0;  
        else if ( $x[0] < $y[0] ) return 1;  
        else return -1;  
    }  
    function compare1($x, $y) {  
        if ( $x[1] == $y[1] ) return 0;  
        else if ( $x[1] < $y[1] ) return 1;  
        else return -1;  
    }  
    function compare2($x, $y) {  
        if ( $x[2] == $y[2] ) return 0;  
        else if ( $x[2] < $y[2] ) return 1;  
        else return -1;  
    }  

} 

################################################## 
#    We get the information here 
################################################## 

$i = 0; 
while($file=$directory->read()) { 
    $file = strtolower($file);
    $ext = strrchr($file, '.');
    if (isset($allowed_ext) && (!in_array($ext,$allowed_ext)))
        {
            // dump 
        }
    else { 
        $temp_info = stat($file); 
        $new_array[$i][0] = $file; 
        $new_array[$i][1] = $temp_info[7]; 
        $new_array[$i][2] = $temp_info[9]; 
        $new_array[$i][3] = date("F d, Y", $new_array[$i][2]); 
        $i = $i + 1; 
        } 
} 
$directory->close(); 

################################################## 
# We sort the information here 
################################################# 

switch ($sort_what) { 
    case 0: 
            usort($new_array, "compare0"); 
    break; 
    case 1: 
            usort($new_array, "compare1"); 
    break; 
    case 2: 
            usort($new_array, "compare2"); 
    break; 
} 

############################################################### 
#    We display the infomation here 
############################################################### 

$i2 = count($new_array); 
$i = 0; 
echo "<table border=1> 
                <tr> 
                    <td width=150> File name</td> 
                    <td width=100> File Size</td> 
                    <td width=100>Last Modified</td> 
                </tr>"; 
for ($i=0;$i<$i2;$i++) { 
    if (!$do_link) { 
        $line = "<tr><td align=right>" .  
                        $new_array[$i][0] .  
                        "</td><td align=right>" .  
                        number_format(($new_array[$i][1]/1024)) .  
                        "k"; 
        $line = $line  . "</td><td align=right>" . $new_array[$i][3] . "</td></tr>"; 
    }else{ 
        $line = '<tr><td align=right><A HREF="' .   
                        $new_array[$i][0] . '">' .  
                        $new_array[$i][0] .  
                        "</A></td><td align=right>"; 
        $line = $line . number_format(($new_array[$i][1]/1024)) .  
                        "k"  . "</td><td align=right>" .  
                        $new_array[$i][3] . "</td></tr>"; 
    } 
    echo $line; 
} 
echo "</table>"; 


?>
```

Comment: This is a "one solution fits all" reply, with all possible eventualities and requirements taken into account.  It's a bit verbose for the common case where some things can be taken for granted.

Answer (score 1):

You should use glob.

```
glob('*.xml')
```

More about using glob and advanced filtering:

http://domexception.blogspot.fi/2013/08/php-using-functional-programming-for.html

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer is to put another condition `'.xml' == strtolower(substr($file, -3))`.

But I'd recommend using `glob` instead too.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the RecursiveFilterIterator class like this:

```
class ExtensionFilter extends RecursiveFilterIterator
{
  /**
  * Hold the extensions pass to the class constructor 
  */
  protected $extensions;

  /**
   * ExtensionFilter constructor.
   *  
   * @param RecursiveIterator $iterator
   * @param string|array $extensions Extension to filter as an array ['php'] or
   * as string with commas in between 'php, exe, ini'
   */
  public function __construct(RecursiveIterator $iterator, $extensions)
  {
     parent::__construct($iterator);
     $this->extensions = is_array($extensions) ? $extensions :  array_map('trim', explode(',', $extensions));
  }

  public function accept()
  {
      if ($this->hasChildren()) {
         return true;
      }

      return $this->current()->isFile() &&
         in_array(strtolower($this->current()->getExtension()), $this->extensions);
  }

  public function getChildren()
  {
     return new self($this->getInnerIterator()->getChildren(), $this->extensions);
  }
```

Now you can  instantiate RecursiveDirectoryIterator with path as an argument like this:

```
 $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('\path\to\dir');
 $iterator = new ExtensionFilter($iterator, 'xml, php, ini');

 foreach($iterator as $file)
 {
   echo $file . '<br />';
 }
```

*This will list files under the current folder only.* 

 
**To get the files in subdirectories also,
pass the $iterator ( ExtensionFIlter Iterator) to RecursiveIteratorIterator as argument:**

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
```

Now run the foreach loop on this iterator. You will get the files with specified extension

***Note:-- Also make sure to run the ExtensionFilter before RecursiveIteratorIterator, otherwise you will get all the files***

Answer (score 0):

The $files array will get all files in the directory which the specified extension

```
$directory = 'pathto/directory';
$files = array();
$allowed_ext = array( "xml", "png", "jpg", "jpeg", "txt", "doc", "xls","csv"); 
// Check if the directory exists or not
if (file_exists($directory) && is_dir($directory)) {
    // Get the files in the directory
    $scan_contents = scandir($directory);
    // Filter out the current (.) and parent (..) directories 
    $files_array = array_diff($scan_contents, array('.', '..'));
    // Get each files of our directory with line break
    foreach ($files_array as $file) {
        //Get the file path
        $file_path = "$directory/$file";
        // Get the file extension
        $file_ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));        
        if (in_array($file_ext, $allowed_ext) ) {
            $files[] = $file_path;
        }
    }
} 
echo '<pre>$files:-';
print_r($files);
echo '</pre>';
```