# How to get the file and directory list in a specific directory

Tags: php, directory, readdir

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP list of specific files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062154/php-list-of-specific-files-in-a-directory)

I want to list all the directories and files that are there in my directory. How i can do this? Below is my code

```
if(opendir("user_files/".$uid."/")) {
var_dump(readdir("user_files/".$uid."/"));
}
```

Comment: use [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) its easy

Comment: [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) works well

Comment: [scandir](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) does exactly this.

Comment: @Baba thnx, plz add this as your answer so that i will accept it

Comment: @Ali Hassan ... when you get the directory list .. what do you plan to do with them ???? Adding just how to list directory would be duplicate

Comment: i will then enlist the files in those directories

Comment: @Ali Hassan are you targeting general files or images ???

Comment: all files images, doc, pdf, xls etc etc

Comment: @Ali Hassan how do you want them output .. , HTML or Just list them .... what version of PHP are you also using ??

Comment: all i want is to list the directories for user, then user will click on any directory and then there will be list of all files in that directory with view and download option

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to List Files in your folder using [FilesystemIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystemiterator.construct.php)

```
$dir = __DIR__;
$fi = new FilesystemIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
echo "<ul>";
printf("<b>Total Files :  %d</b>", iterator_count($fi));
foreach ( $fi as $file ) {
    printf("<li>%s : %d</li>", $file->getFileName(), $file->getSize());
}
echo "</ul>";
```