# List all files from X date

Tags: php

I am trying to make a script that will list all files in a directory created (or modified) on the date given in a $_GET request.

I have a script that lists all files and the dates but how.would I be able to 'order' them into a way where I can use my $_GET request. Knowing me it is something really simple, here is what I have already:

```
<?php putenv("TZ=Europe/London");
if ($handle = opendir('./Images/')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
           echo "$entry : " . date ("d/m/y", filemtime($entry))."<br />";
        }
    }
closedir($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will throw a stat error as it is looking for the filetime in the current directory.

Notice the filetime function contained the directory (filemtime($dir.$entry)

Try this

```
$dir = './Images'; // use a variable so you can easily use this again

if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
       if(filemtime($dir.$entry) == $_GET['date']) // set date paramter in the format of d/m/y
          echo "$entry : " . date ("d/m/y", filemtime($dir.$entry))."<br />"; // notice './Images'
    }
}
closedir($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **full** PHP LIST FILES script from this page -

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062154/php-list-of-specific-files-in-a-directory/15678731#15678731
```

**But, on line 135, instead of**

```
echo $line;
```

**Use this** *(change date to your desired)*

```
if ( $new_array[$i][2] > strtotime('2013-03-19 17:14:40') ) {
echo $line;
}
```