# How to Display Directory Files on a PHP/HTML Webpage?

Tags: php, html, css, interface, directory

I am willing to show the files' list of a web directory on a web page.

But I am not understanding about how to do that.

Can any one give me some easy guideline so that I can do it?

Better any raw code (HTML,CSS,PHP,JS) so that I can understand the way to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP list of specific files in a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062154/php-list-of-specific-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate. That question is about "Listing specific Files", but my question is about "Listing entire directory details" like a PC directory shows.

Comment: "The following code will list all the file in a directy" which is what you want. its a duplicate of hundreds of others to, but like you im to lazy to search

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your web server, you can enable directory listing. For example, in apache, you can delete your index.html and index.php file and enable directory listing in your `.htaccess` file.

If you're using PHP, use `scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to read a list of files in the current directory and print them to the screen.

```
$files = scandir( "MY_DIRECTORY" );
foreach( $files as $file ){
   echo $file . "<br />";
}
```