# Listing certain extensions in PHP Dir List

Tags: php, list, dir

Have the following to provide a dir list in an array

```
for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
        if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != ".") { // don't list hidden files
 echo "<option value=\"".$dirArray[$index]."\">".$dirArray[$index]."</option>";
 }
```

Is there any way i can modify the above code so that only .JPG and .PNG are displayed?

Thanks!

CP

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP list of specific files in a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062154/php-list-of-specific-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: `"$dirArray[$index]"` cargo cult programming detected... Perhaps you want http://php.net/pathinfo to extract file extensions from filenames.

Comment: There are some similarities but I can't see how without rewriting everything that I would be able to get these types listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression to match if file name ends with `.jpg` or `.png`

```
for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) 
{
    if(preg_match("/^.*\.(jpg|png)$/i", $dirArray[$index]) == 1) 
    {
      echo "<option value=\"".$dirArray[$index]."\">".$dirArray[$index]."</option>";
    }
}
```

`/i` at the end of regular expression is case insensitive flag.

Comment: Hey Harshveer, thanks for your help.  Have had a go at doing this but it still displays the other types.   What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($dirArray[$index] as $k => $v) {
     if(in_array(pathinfo($v, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg')) {
         echo '<option value="'.$v.'">'.$v.'</option>';
     }
}
```

I am assuming some things about your array of files. Also is there a reason you're not using the readdir() function?

Answer (score 0):

```
for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
        if (substr($dirArray[$index], 0, 1) != "." 
            && strtolower(substr($dirArray[$index], -3)) == 'png' 
            && strtolower(substr($dirArray[$index], -3)) == 'jpg')
            echo '<option value="'.$dirArray[$index].'">'.$dirArray[$index].'</option>';
 }
```

This should work, but there are more elegant solutions to this, like using `DirectoryIterator` (see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/ro/directoryiterator.getextension.php)):

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('your_directory') as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot() 
        || !in_array($fileInfo->getExtension(), array('png', 'jpg'))) 
        continue;
    echo sprintf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', 
        $fileInfo->getFilename(), 
        $fileInfo->getFilename());
}
```

Code not tested, you might need to fiddle a bit with it.