# PHP - get all filenames in dir by pattern

Tags: php, file, laravel, directory, filenames

I found this code to iterate through files in folder:

```
if (is_dir($dir)) {
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {

          ???????????

  }
    closedir($dh);
}
```

Files have names like: `project-1-0, project-1-1, project-5-14, project-6-21 ...`
Now I need to filter all files and get only these that begins with "project-1-??" How could I do that, should I use `blob()` function? Is there any simple example? Im using laravel so maybe there is  a function in it for that but i couldnt find  something useful

Comment: use $file to check the name for each one?

Comment: `glob()` is the way to go

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP list of specific files in a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062154/php-list-of-specific-files-in-a-directory). But use the most voted answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922954/getting-the-names-of-all-files-in-a-directory-with-php

Comment: `print_r(glob("{$file}*", GLOB_BRACE));` , check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glob` is very much what you want here. However, being as you appear to be using Laravel (due to the tag), you should look at Laravel's `FileSystem` class (accessible using the `File` facade): [4.2 docs](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html). It provides a wrapper for the standard PHP file functions (though doesn't actually add anything to the mix really for your purposes).

You can do stuff like this:

```
if (File::isDirectory($dir)) {
    foreach (File::glob($dir.'/project-1-*') as $projectDir) {
        $actualDir = substr($projectDir, strlen($dir) + 1); // trim the base directory
    }
}
```

But if you want a more powerful file-finding system, you can use Symfony's `Finder` component ([docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html)), which is already included in your project if you're using Laravel (as *some* Laravel `Filesystem` methods use it) and you'll be able to do things like this:

```
$dirs = Finder::create()->in($dir)->depth(0)->directories()->name('project-1-*');
// or, if you want to use regex, this should work
$dirs = Finder::create()->in($dir)->depth(0)->directories()->name('/^project-1-/');
```

Now, Finder returns an iterator, so you can use PHP's `iterator_to_array` function to turn it into an array if you need to use it as an array (that said, an iterator is better if you don't need it as an array, for instance `foreach`ing over it).