# PHP glob a directory going wrong in some cases why?

Tags: php

I have a mistery with my PHP code going wrong in some cases and I don't understand why. 
My current code is displaying all photos related to the client by a range.

Example: pick all inside the folder from pictures 300 to 310 and display them.

Example of photos names inside my folder: C20_0385, C20_0386, C20_0389, C20_0400...

Current PHP code: with photos from 385 to 420.

```
$start = 385:
$end = 420;

$dirname = "smallphotos/$jour_creation - $date_creation/$session/$dossier";

$filenames = glob("$dirname/*{" . implode(",", range($start, $end)) . "}*", GLOB_BRACE);

foreach ($filenames as $filename)
{
echo "<img class=\"img-responsive\" src=\"$filename\" alt=\"$filename\">";
}
```

That works perfectly and now if I do `$start = 385; $end = 450;`

It write errors:

```
Warning: glob(): Pattern exceeds the maximum allowed length of 260 characters
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

If I do from `$start = 385; $end = 435;` it shows the whole folder currently up to C20_503.JPG

It looks like for small range more or less 40 photos it does the job but for more something is going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error states that the glob pattern cannot be longer than 260 characters; you're going to have to use [an alternative approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062154/php-list-of-specific-files-in-a-directory):

```
$filenames = array();
$dir = opendir( $dirname );
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir)))
{
    if ( is_file( $file ) && preg_match( "/^.*?_(\d+)/", $file, $m )
      && $m[1] >= $start && $m[1] <= $end
    )
        $filenames[] = "$dirname/$file";
}
closedir($handle);
```

Comment: Your code is interesting. I will test it this night thank you

Answer (score 2):

This function `range($start, $end)` is generating a set of numbers.

When you `$start = 385; and $end = 420;` the list contains 35 entries

When you `$start = 385; and $end = 435;` the list contains 50 entries

It is this that is making the `Pattern exceeds the maximum allowed length of 260 characters` error

You will have to limit the numbers so you dont cause the generated string to exceed the allowed length.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand what is going on. Those 260 characters isn't it a Windows limitation? I mean if i'm on Linux server this isn't anymore a problem?

Comment: No see this http://serverfault.com/questions/9546/filename-length-limits-on-linux

Comment: Anyway I think its a limit of the `glob` function and nothing to do with a OS filepath limitation.

Comment: Ok this is good to know. Thank you for all your help and informations !