# PHP get list of files matching a pattern and sort by oldest file

Tags: php, regex, file, directory, glob

if I have a directory, where a list of file looks like this:

```
Something_2015020820.txt
something_5294032944.txt.a
something_2015324234.txt
Something_2014435353.txt.a
```

and I want to get the list of file **sort by oldest date** (not the filename) and the result should take anything that match something_xxxxxxx.txt. So, anything that ends with ".a" is not included. in this case it should return

```
Something_2015020820.txt
something_2015324234.txt
```

I do some google search and it seems like I can use glob

```
$listOfFiles = glob($this->directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->pattern . "*");
```

but I'm not sure about the pattern.

It would be awesome if you could provide both **case sensitive and insensitive pattern**. The match pattern will have to be something_number.txt

Answer (score 7):

It's a bit tricky using glob. It does support some limited pattern matching. For example you can do

`glob("*.[tT][xX][tT]");`

This will match `file.txt` and `file.TXT`, but it will also match `file.tXt` and `file.TXt`. Unfortunately there is no way to specify something like `file.(txt or TXT)`. If that's not a problem, great! Otherwise, you'll have to first use this method to at least narrow the results down, and then perform some additional processing afterwards. array_filter and some regex maybe.

A better option might be to use PHP's Iterator classes, so you can specify much more advanced rules.

```
$directoryIterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory);
$iteratorIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directoryIterator);
$fileList = new RegexIterator($iteratorIterator, '/^.*\.(txt|TXT)$/');
foreach($fileList as $file) {
    echo $file;
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but how files would be ordered?

Comment: Did not work for me using PHP for Windows.
This however worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3062168/4063622

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `scandir` to get all your files. Then `preg_match` to filter those files down to ones that don't end with `.a`. Then `filemtime` can be used to pull the time the file was last modified.  `array_multisort` can then be used to sort by the time the file was last modified and maintain the key/filename association.

This works as I expected:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); //change to your timezone
$directory = 'Your Directory';
$files = scandir($directory);
foreach($files as $file) {
    if(!preg_match('~\.a$~', $file) && !is_dir($directory . $file)) {
        $time["$file"] = filemtime($upload_directory . $file);
    }
}
array_multisort($time);
```

Then to handle the outputting you could do something like:

```
foreach($time as $file => $da_time){
    echo $file . ' '. date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $da_time) . "\n";
}
```

The `preg_match` can have `i` added after the `~` delimiter so the regex is case insensitive; or you could just make change the `a` to `[aA]`.