# PHP for get full url of all files within the folder where is it executed?

Tags: php

There is a way in PHP for run a script that retrieve the full URL of every files within the folder where the scipt is executed?
Thank you

Comment: This will help: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP list of specific files in a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062154/php-list-of-specific-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: @Dagon 1= ? instead of =?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the URL is not so easy.  PHP does not always work in a manner of path relating to URL.  Your environment might be setup so the path=URL, or it might be setup so that all requests are sent to one PHP controller that then computes the result.

To find the paths however is quite straight forward.

```
$directory = __DIR__; //Gets the current directory path
$contents = scandir($directory); //Get all files and folders from the $directory
$contents = array_diff($contents, array('..', '.')); //If a linux environment, this removes the ".." and "." occurences
```

[Scandir documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use iterator to go over the directory. Then use pathinfo() to get the complete path of the file.