# Echo content of multiple html file with PHP

Tags: php, html

I try to echo whole content of every html file in specific directory.

I know that i can use `readfile()` to read and return content of specific file. How can i use it with every html file in specific directory ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: read the directory to get all file names in there. Iterate over them, open to read them, and echo them. Hit up php.net

Comment: no need to open/read/echo.. just include

Answer (score 0):

You could store the content of the files with `file_get_contents()`.

This function (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3062204/1762556)) will return either a 2D array where `$key => $value` pairs are represented by `$filename => $file_content` or `false` if it fails to open the directory.

```
<?php
function read_htmlfiles_in_dir($dir)
{
    $files = array();
    if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
        {
            if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && strtolower(substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1)) == 'html')
            {
                $files[$file] = file_get_contents($file);
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
        return ($files);
    }
    else
    {
        return (false);
    }
}
?>
```

include this somewhere then you can to this for example if you need to echo all the `html` files in the curent directory :

```
<?php
if ($htmlfiles = read_htmlfiles_in_dir('.'))
{
    foreach($htmlfiles as $file)
    {
        echo $file;
    }
}
?>
```

of you need a little debug you just

```
print_r($htmlfiles);
```

and get something like

```
Array
(
    [filename.html] => <div>Some HTML Code</div>
    [otherfile.html] => <span>Some <b>other</b> HTML code</span>

)
```

You will however have one last thing to think about : the order in which the HTML files have to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

or you could do somrthing much simpler..

```
$FILES = scandir("/complete/path/to/directory");
foreach($FILES as $FILE)
    if($FILE == "." || $FILE == "..") continue;
    else include($FILE);
```

if it's the current directory..

```
$FILES = scandir(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
foreach($FILES as $FILE)
        if($FILE == "." || $FILE == ".." || $FILE ==  __FILE__) continue;
        else include($FILE);
```

Comment: yes if you consider that we only need to echo the html content whatever the order.

Comment: if there was an order i imagine he would do it manually rather than looping every one..