# PHP get exe files in a specific directory, ignore other files and folders

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find the best method of selecting .exe files within a directory, ignoring files inside other directories.

So far, I have the following:

`$files = scandir('/path/to/dir');`

Now, how can I remove "..", "." and other directories and files within that directory that are not .exe files?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP list of specific files in a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062154/php-list-of-specific-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: By iterating through the entries and filtering them, obviously. Or you simply use the ``glob()`` function.

Comment: @arkascha mind helping me there? I saw the glob() function, but wasn't able to understand exactly how it works.

Comment: The documentation of the `glob()` functions comes with easy examples, I do not really see what might be difficult to follow there. Would you mind asking in a more specific way so that we can offer specific help?

Comment: The linked thread has `glob` examples, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3062165/4333555 (the accepted answer isn't always the best one).

Comment: @chris85 AWESOME. Thanks. found the solution there. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$files = glob('path/to/dir/*.exe');
```

Thanks @chris85